# JQuery Nested sortable Syntax Error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hey I am trying to do the nested sorting using jQuery I am getting a syntax error Can anyone figure it out I cant see any syntax error.
My code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
        disableNesting: 'no-nest',
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        handle: 'div',
        helper: 'clone',
        items: 'li',
        maxLevels: 3,
        opacity: .6,
        placeholder: 'placeholder',
        revert: 250,
        tabSize: 25,
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        toleranceElement: '> div',
        connectWith: '.sortable'
    });​
});
</script>
```

rest of the code is just HTML not logic till now.
I am getting this error

**SyntaxError: syntax error
});?
test.html (line 30, col 5)**

Thanks

Comment: No error that I can see. One of many problems of having JS amongst your HTML is that the line numbers in error reports are skewed. Put things in separate JS files.

Comment: The line number it is giving in the error is in the JQuery not in HTML

Comment: @Utkanos Exactly the same code works here http://jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/Ge7eK/9/ but not on my local system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just guessing by the col number... remove the `;` at the end of nestedSortable().

Comment: Now it says TypeError: $("ol.sortable").nestedSortable is not a function

Comment: I see. The nestedSortable you're using is a plugin. It's not part of jquery UI, you need to include the plugin script.

Comment: but its not included here jsfiddle.net/jhogervorst/Ge7eK/9

Comment: Can you please tell me which files should I include to make it working?

Comment: Download it [here](https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable/blob/master/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js) and include it after jquery-ui
And [here](http://f.cl.ly/items/0P311r3a2x2C1x0z1w2R/jquery.ui.nestedSortable.js) is the exact version of the jsfiddle

Comment: Can I use onStop method in this plugin ?